# yum update doesn't update the package

Tags: redhat, yum, rhel7

I'm on RHEL 7. Security team suggested me to update `curl` and `dbus` packages. When I try `yum update` , it says

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
No packages marked for update
```

I verified that the packages are old as mentioned by security team.

Below are the screenshots I received from security team.
[image]
[image]

How can I update the packages as suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update RHEL without a Red Hat subscription. Your system is not registered with an entitlement server, as it states. Do you have a Red Hat license?

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting to CentOS 7 which is 100% binary compatible with RHEL:

https://www.openlogic.com/blog/step-step-migration-rhel-74-centos-74

Or simply grab CentOS updates and install them manually via

`rpm -Uvh [packages]`